# create repetition of elements multidimentional

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a repetition of elements given array like this `[1,2,10]` to get the result by **size** `n`, if size `n` equals `2` the result is `[ [1,1], [1,2], [1,10], [2,2], [2, 10], [10, 10] ]`
i am trying to recursion it without any magic function javascript , just do push and pop :),
here is my code

```
function t(arr, length,  i = 0, result = []) {
  let final = []
  if( result.length == length){
    final.push(result)
    console.log(final)
    return 
  }

  let j = i;
  while( j < arr.length ) {
    result.push(arr[j])
    // console.log(result)
    t(arr, length, j, result)

    result.pop()
    j++
  }
  return final
}


function k() {
  const arr = [1,2,10]
  const l = 2
  return t(arr, l)
}

console.log( "finall result ===> " , k())
```

the `final` result is an **empty** array, though on condition above I push `result` to array empty of `final`,
is there any wrong in my code?

expected result : `[ [1,1], [1,2], [1,10], [2,2], [2, 10], [10, 10] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and iterate the array without mutating the array.

```js
function getCombinations(array, n) {
    function iter(index, right) {
        if (right.length === n) {
            result.push(right);
            return;
        }
        while (index < array.length) {
            iter(index, [...right, array[index]]);
            index++;
        }    
    }
    
    var result = [];
    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombinations([1, 2, 10], 2));
```

Comment: how about if `iter(index, [...right, array[index]]);`  without `three dot`  that ?

Comment: you could take `concat` instead.